# Underscore rendering [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have an underscore template that is appending the following text "**[object HTMLDivElement]**"
, but it's supposed to append value that "model.get('title')" returns.

Here's my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="todoTemplate">
  <div class='todoBlock'>
    <li class='appendedTodo'>
      <%= title %>
    </li>
    <button class='delete'>Delete</button><p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Here's my function:

```
  addTodoLi: function(model){
    var todoData = model.get('title');
    var compileTemplate = _.template( $('#todoTemplate').html() );
    $('#todo-list').append( compileTemplate(todoData) );
  },
```

Comment: I made a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuclearghost/z24A4/) that is working, but didn't do all the backbone things it looks like you are.  If you want to fork the fiddle with additional things that break it, I can help more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `todoData` is (presumably) a string:

```
var todoData = model.get('title');
```

but a compiled [Underscore template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) wants a key/value object as its argument:

> When you evaluate a template function, pass in a **data** object that has properties corresponding to the template's free variables.

Looks like you have a `title` global variable or `window` property that is a `<div>` DOM object or you would get a ReferenceError complaining about an unknown `title` variable instead of a stringified DOM object.

In any case, the fix is pretty easy: give the template function what it wants:

```
$('#todo-list').append(compileTemplate({ title: todoData }));
```

or the common Backbone approach:

```
$('#todo-list').append(compileTemplate(model.toJSON()));
```

There are cases where the model will have optional attributes that the templates need to access. In such cases, you might have:

```
<%= pancakes %>
```

in the template but sometimes `toJSON` will give you:

```
{ title: 'x' }
```

and other times you'll get:

```
{ title: 'x', pancakes: 11 }
```

In such case you need to "un-optionalize" the optional attributes in your `toJSON`: `toJSON` should supply everything. If you have attributes that are optional then `toJSON` should ensure that it returns them with `undefined` or `null` values.

Comment: Thanks Mu, you hit it on the head.
In the second more conventional Backbone approach where you pass in a "model.toJSON", where do you use the "get" method to get the model's title property?

Comment: @gh0st: [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) does `_.clone(this.attributes)` so it is the same doing a `o[a] = model.get(a)` for each attribute `a` in the model.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore Template Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/underscore-template-editor) might be of some help to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If it is from another view I use `.html()` or `.outerHTML` like this:

```
otherview: view.render().$el.html()
otherview: view.render().el.outerHTML
```